# Trying to access array offset on value of type bool / Database

Tags: php

I have an app and use PHP 7.4 It states that I have an error in the code: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool.

Here is the code:

```
    $this->Database->Query("SELECT data FROM ". TABLE_PREFIX ."registry WHERE vkey = '". $this->Database->Escape($_keyName) ."'", 5);
    $this->Database->NextRecord(5);

    if ($this->Database->Record5["data"] != "") <--- AN ERROR HERE??
    {
        $this->UpdateLocalCache($_keyName, $this->Database->Record5["data"]);

        return $this->Database->Record5["data"];
```

I tried updating the code, but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: It seems that `$this->Database->Record5` is actually `false` (or, perhaps less likely, `true`), then. It's hard to tell what the expectation would be, as this seems to involve some sort of custom class whose contents we know nothing about, and a database whose contents we also know nothing about. A [mre] of the issue would really help us to help you. See also [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: `I tried updating the code, but it doesn't work`...we don't know what changes you made, or exactly what the outcome was (doesn't work explains nothing useful at all), so unless you intend to tell us about it there's very little point in mentioning this :-)

Comment: Are you sure the query found a matching row? `false` is a likely value if there's no record returned. You need to test for this before trying to access values in the row.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether the query returned anything before trying to access columns.

```
if ($this->Database->Record5) {
    if ($this->Database->Record5["data"] != "") {
        $this->UpdateLocalCache($_keyName, $this->Database->Record5["data"]);
        return $this->Database->Record5["data"];
    } else {
        // report that data is empty
    }
} else {
    // report that $_keyname was not found
}
```